# "match is null" only at server - jQuery 1.x

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

got a problem with this little piece of code:

```
$('.desc_container').each(function() {
    var fulltext = $(this).text();
    if(fulltext.length > 50) {
      var myRegexp = /^(.{47}\w*\W)(.*?)$/g;
      var match = myRegexp.exec(fulltext);
      var open_part = match[1];
      var hidden_part = match[2];
      $(this).html(open_part + '<span class="hidden">' + hidden_part + '</span><span class="expand">more..</span>');
    }
})
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7buu6ra9/3/)

When I'm testing it locally or at jsfiddle everything is pretty fine, but trying this on server returning "match is null". The only difference is that on the server the desc_container is filled by **smarty**, but that should not matter because the script is loaded on $(document).ready(function()...
 jQuery version: 1.11.
 Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, problem was with linebreaks at production in generated content, regex should look like that

```
^([\s\S]{47}\w*\W)([\s\S]*?)$
```